# Flutter background iOS notification don't work in XCode or TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, testflight

I am trying to receive background push-notifications on an IOS device using Flutter. I have managed to get this to work on Android and it also works on iOS debug if I run code with Android Studio, but when I run code using XCode I can't get background notifications and I get this:

**2020-05-19 01:45:43.617423-0700 Runner[924:720398] dnssd_clientstub read_all(22) DEFUNCT**

**2020-05-19 01:45:43.618224-0700 Runner[924:720398] [VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(131)] Could not register as server for FlutterObservatoryPublisher. Check your network settings and relaunch the application.**

**2020-05-19 01:45:43.657713-0700 Runner[924:720653] [] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"**

**2020-05-19 01:45:43.661093-0700 Runner[924:720653] [] nw_read_request_report [C1] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"**

Notifications also don't work in TestFlight.
Can you help me, please?

Now I am using
  `firebase_messaging: ^6.0.15` but with the previous version, I got the same situation.

My flutter doctor --verbose:

```sh
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.0, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale it-IT) 

• Flutter version 1.17.0 at /Users/xxxxx/development/flutter  

• Framework revision e6b34c2b5c (2 settimane fa), 2020-05-02 11:39:18 -0700    

• Engine revision 540786dd51    

• Dart version 2.8.1 

 [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)   

• Android SDK at /Users/xxxxx/Library/Android/sdk  

 • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3    

• Java binary at: /Applications/Android   Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java   

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)   

• All Android licenses accepted. 

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)    

• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer  

• Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a   

• CocoaPods version 1.9.1 

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)    

• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents  

• Flutter plugin version 45.1.1    

• Dart plugin version 192.7761     

• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build      1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211) 

[✓] VS Code (version 1.44.2)     

• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents     

• Flutter extension version 3.10.1   

[✓] Connected device (1 available)    

  • iPhone • ios • iOS      13.4.1
```

Answer (score 0):

change your appDelegate like this :

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    }
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }

    override func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    }

    override func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    }
}
```